# NoClassDefFoundError for Stanford NLP library

Tags: java, ant, stanford-nlp, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

I am using Stanford NLP library for an IBM Bluemix app. I have added both `stanford-corenlp-3.5.1-models.jar` and `stanford-corenlp-3.5.1.jar` to build path. And consequently, the app is running fine in the local webshpere liberty server.

When I build the WAR file through ant build of `build.xml`, I ensure that both the files are included. I can also see them present inside the WAR file. But when I deploy the WAR file on Bluemix, and run it, I get the following error:

> ERR java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP

What might be the problem?

I have ensured that the jar file is in the war file:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the jar files are present in the WEB-INF\lib  folder in the WAR file.

I have faced the same issue and by making the jar available in WEB-INF\lib folder it was resolved.

Comment: Hi Vishal,  I see that some of the jars are quite huge. If i sum up , it crosses at least 330 MB. Also there are some redundant jars.  You dont need db2jcc.jar and db2jcc4.jar together. So just wondering what is the memory you have allocated to the app while pushing.  You can specify somewhat more memory using the -m argument when pushing you war file.   cf push <appname> -p <pathtowar> -m <memory>.   Also do you have any staging errors ?  Can you please send me the staging log file. You can get the logs by running the command cf logs <appname> --recent.